# Building C++ project No lib.so cannot open shared object or directory, but its in linker args and file is present in folder

Tags: c++, gcc, build, linker, shared-libraries

Im building c++ application on Ubuntu 22.04 with Meson with gcc 11.3.0 (it also uses ccache which I tried to clear). Im struggling with one particular library, which I connect to the project as

```
triton_grpcclient_dep = declare_dependency(link_args : ['-L' + triton_client_lib_dir, '-lgrpcclient'],
                               include_directories : [triton_client_inc_dir])

message('Found grpc: ', triton_grpcclient_dep.found())
```

Which prints

```
Message: Found grpc:  true
```

And this .so file in the folder indeed:

```
ldd ../../2.27.0_triton_client/lib/libgrpcclient.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffeeb93000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f090e199000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f090e106000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f090de30000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f090de2b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f090dc01000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f090db18000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f090daf8000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f090d8d0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f090eafc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f090d8cb000)
```

When Im building my app I have following linker output:

```
c++  -o mi-app mi-app.p/meson-generated_sources.grpc.pb.cc.o mi-app.p/meson-generated_sources.pb.cc.o mi-app.p/main.cpp.o mi-app.p/MediaInferenceApp.cpp.o mi-app.p/TritonClient.cpp.o mi-app.p/TritonModel.cpp.o mi-app.p/MainDetector.cpp.o mi-app.p/SharedData.cpp.o mi-app.p/Input.cpp.o mi-app.p/Output.cpp.o mi-app.p/Dispatcher.cpp.o mi-app.p/VehicleExpert.cpp.o mi-app.p/GSInput.cpp.o mi-app.p/DatabaseConnect.cpp.o mi-app.p/AMQPConnect.cpp.o mi-app.p/Config.cpp.o mi-app.p/Log.cpp.o mi-app.p/grpc_media_portal.cpp.o mi-app.p/json_utils.cc.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_MultiTracker.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_BYTETracker.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_kalmanFilter.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_lapjv.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_PTrack.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_ParkedVehicle.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_VTrack.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_VehicleTracker.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_TrackerObj.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_ParkingTracker.cpp.o mi-app.p/NexCity.Media.MultiTrack_src_utils.cpp.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/lib -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -Wl,--start-group -lgrpcclient -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lhttpclient -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_distributions -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cordz_info -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_throw_delegate -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lprotobuf -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_demangle_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_stacktrace -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_raw_hash_set -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_bad_optional_access -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_strerror -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cord -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_bad_any_cast_impl -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_program_name -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_log_severity -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_bad_variant_access -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_config -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_symbolize -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_private_handle_accessor -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_randen -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_leak_check -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_parse -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_commandlineflag -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_usage -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_platform -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_scoped_set_env -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lgrpc_unsecure -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lgrpc++ -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -laddress_sorting -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_time_zone -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_debugging_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_hash -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cord_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_civil_time -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_distribution_test_util -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_seed_sequences -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_graphcycles_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_city -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_int128 -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lupb -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cordz_functions -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cordz_handle -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_cordz_sample_token -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_marshalling -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_str_format_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_spinlock_wait -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_strings -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_malloc_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_periodic_sampler -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lcares -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_base -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_reflection -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_statusor -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_usage_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_flags -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_time -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_failure_signal_handler -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lgrpc++_reflection -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_synchronization -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_strings_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_low_level_hash -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_exponential_biased -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_status -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lgpr -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_raw_logging_internal -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -labsl_examine_stack -L/home/superman/projects/spdlog/build -lspdlog /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_alphamat.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_aruco.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_barcode.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bgsegm.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_bioinspired.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ccalib.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dnn_objdetect.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dnn_superres.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dpm.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_face.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_freetype.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_fuzzy.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hdf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_hfs.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_img_hash.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_intensity_transform.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_line_descriptor.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_mcc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_quality.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rapid.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_reg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_rgbd.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_saliency.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_shape.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stereo.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_structured_light.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_optflow.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_surface_matching.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_tracking.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_datasets.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_text.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_plot.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videoio.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_viz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_wechat_qrcode.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ximgproc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xobjdetect.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgcodecs.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_dnn.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_xphoto.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -pthread /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstpbutils-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstrtp-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so /usr/local/lib/libuv.so /usr/local/lib/libamqpcpp.so /usr/local/lib/libyaml-cpp.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.80.0 /usr/local/lib/libz.so -L/home/superman/opt/lib -lssl -L/home/superman/opt/lib -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group
```

It has a lot of libs, this links libgrpcclient:

```
-L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -Wl,--start-group -lgrpcclient -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib -lhttpclient -L/home/superman/projects/2.27.0_triton_client/lib
```

Problem is when app is finished building, it wont launch, saying

```
./app: error while loading shared libraries: libgrpcclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

 ldd ./app
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff36344000)
        libgrpcclient.so => not found
        libhttpclient.so => not found
```

I do not understand why it wont link library.

Another weird thing is, I previously built with other version of libgrpcclient.so (2.20), and this one 2.27. I've noticed linker still picks up 2.20 version if its on old path, so I moved it to 2.20__. If I change path back to 2.20 and build, I get this:

```
ldd ./app
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe8b44000)
        libgrpcclient.so => /home/superman/projects/v2.20.0_ubuntu2004.clients/lib/libgrpcclient.so (0x00007f74e4404000)
        libhttpclient.so => /home/superman/projects/v2.20.0_ubuntu2004.clients/lib/libhttpclient.so (0x00007f74e4370000)
```

And launching app gives error

```
./app symbol lookup error: ./app: undefined symbol: _ZN6triton6client25InferenceServerGrpcC....
```

which is some function from this lib. Error probably happens because compiler gets include headers from 2.27 version, but linkers links it with 2.20 .so. It must mean 2.20 library path stuck somewhere as linker can link to it? librpcclient.so not in a system folder. Im not sure what places to check because Im no Linux expert.

But even if path stuck somewhere, when I rename folder linker no longer able to find it, and I supply path to new library location, but it do not uses it? What could be the reason here?

Answer (score 0):

I actually forgot that some long time ago I've put this 2.20 library into `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`, so `ldconfig` maps dependency onto 2.20 version. I removed record and everything works.